# Is there a way in sqldeveloper to have a visual indicator if a worksheet has certain connections?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want a warning if the SQL Developer has a connection to a production database, so that I don't accidentally change production data, thinking I am in a development environment.

For instance, if my worksheet has a connection to a prod database, turn its background yellow.  This would be a good safeguard for developers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - set the connection color property. you'll get a colored border for any screen associated with that connection.

That color will also be used for the connection label in the connection panel and any connection selector.

Here's what Yellow looks like.

[image]

Comment: always the best Jeff

Answer (score 1):

The connection has a property called "color". The effect is that the connection name in the "connections" pane has that color and the worksheet has a colored border around it. I verified on 19.4 which is not the latest version.